# ArcGIS for Server - Web Map Services

Tags: arcgis-server, wms

I have a WMS that I would like to consume with ArcGIS for Server.  The WMS is secured by way of an IP whitelist, and network connectivity from the server to the WMS has been verified.

Is there a way to consume this WMS and then re-publish as a service to the ArcGIS API for Javascript?

Calling the WMS directly from the Javascript code is not an option as each client will have a different IP address, and this will be unknown until run-time.  I therefore won't be able to pre-populate the IP whitelist with a list of all known IP addresses.

I know I can do this with MapServer, but hoping not to have to move down the path of having multiple software components installed on the infrastructure.

Comment: This functionality is sometimes known as cascading map services.